# Sample size to minimize false negatives in screening.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am one of a group of four in a literature screening team for a meta-analysis. We have approximately 2200 search results to screen for the studies that most fit our inclusion criteria. Each of us is screening about 550 studies, and we are QCing each others' work to ensure there are no errors. What is the smallest number of results screened by my colleague I have to screen, in order to ensure that the false negative rate is below a given value (say 10%)? How would I approach the problem, and what statistical approach would I use?

Comment: What does reviewing entail--you redo his decision whether to include the article (perhaps on some subset of his 550) and how do you resolve conflicts (since you could be introducing errors at that stage)? Or do you assume that the reviewer's assessment is a gold standard?

Comment: Q1) The decision would entail me redoing the decision - I would give it my own rating, whether to include or exclude it.                                                                                                 Q2) The reviewer's (i.e me in the case of my colleague, my colleague in my case) assessment is the gold standard. How does the question of conflict resolution affect the statistical approach?